# Predicting price using previous prices with R and Neural Networks (neuralnet)

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, mathematical-expressions

Within the R Neural Network page, I am using the neural network function to attempt to predict stock price.

Training data contains columns High,Low,Open,Close.

```
myformula <- close ~ High+Low+Open
neuralnet(myformula,data=train_,hidden=c(5,3),linear.output=T)
```

My question, Given the below data example could you tell me what the formula would look like.

I have a table with columns "High","Low","Open","Close" it has two rows of values, each row represents a candle stick for the day. So the two rows in the data are candle sticks for the previous two days.My aim is tp predict what the next candle stick is i.e. "Open","High","Low","Close" given the previous two candlesticks.

My neural network will be presented with the previous dtata 1 candle stick at a time. I want to know what the next candlestick is, so what would my R formula look like.

Thanks
Let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My neural network will be presented with the previous data one candle stick at a time. I want to know what the next candlestick is, so what would my R formula look like.

In a Feed-Forward Neural Network*, you have to specify the features you want to use for the prediction and the targets to predict. In your example above the feature is e.g. `prev_close`, and the target is `close`. As you can see in your training data you don't have `prev_close` yet, that was the whole point of my answer, you need to formulate the problem correctly first.

If all you have is `close`, there cannot be a formula to train a FF NN for this. You need to create `prev_close` then the formula would be `close ~ prev_close`.

<sub>**A Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) can be trained on sequences, and  output a prediction based on an input sequence, but that's a whole 'nother can of worms*</sub>

### Simple example: predict close based on last 2 close values

I cooked up this ridiculously-simplistic* example just to illustrate the problem formulation, that predicts the `close`, based one the last two `close` values. I chose a single hidden layer with 1 neuron in it. I've set `linear.output=TRUE` since we are predicting continuous values ([regression problem as discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939936/artifcial-neural-networks-for-prediction/37940043#37940043), and in the [`neuralnet` documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/neuralnet.pdf) it is stated that there will be no activation function `act.fct` if that value is TRUE)

<sub>**If you trade with this you will certainly lose your shirt. This is just to show how to structure such a prediction problem in a Neural Network. Don't use this for real.*</sub>

### Problem formulation

The point I wanted to make clear is this, if you have prices in a column you have to create the features for the prediction

```
prev_close_1 | prev_close_2 | close
```

The problem posed to the NN is to predict `close` based on `prev_close_1` and `prev_close_2`, hence the formula `close ~ prev_close_1 + prev_close_2`

**Here's the network architecture**

[image]

Notice the inputs that are the previous close values, and the output: the predicted close value.

```
library(neuralnet)

N = 10
prices <- data.frame(close=1:N) # Dummy straight line uptrend for N periods 

print(prices)

shift <- function(x, n){
  c(x[-(seq(n))], rep(NA, n))
}

# Form the training dataframe
train <- data.frame(
  prev_close_1=prices$close,
  prev_close_2=shift(prices$close, 1),
  close=shift(prices$close, 2)
)

# When shifting the columns for time lag effect, some rows will have NAs
# Let's remove NAs
train <- na.omit(train)

print(train)

nn <- neuralnet(
  formula=close ~ prev_close_1 + prev_close_2,
  data=train,
  hidden=c(1), # 1 neuron in a single hidden layer
  linear.output=TRUE # we want regression not classification
)

print(prediction(nn))
plot(nn)
```

### What the dummy prices look like

This is what you have, it's just the historical stock prices

```
   close
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      6
7      7
8      8
9      9
10    10
```

### What the NN was trained on

This is what you need, the features and the target, try to form the rows in the training dataframe below to understand the shift/lag.

```
prev_close_1 prev_close_2 close
1            1            2     3
2            2            3     4
3            3            4     5
4            4            5     6
5            5            6     7
6            6            7     8
7            7            8     9
8            8            9    10
```

### What the NN predicts

```
  prev_close_1 prev_close_2       close
1            1            2 2.994291864
2            2            3 4.017828301
3            3            4 5.002914789
4            4            5 5.968855729
5            5            6 6.978644849
6            6            7 8.030810042
7            7            8 9.051063456
8            8            9 9.945595495
```

Comment: thanks , however referring to the first case close ~ open + high + low, why wouldnt R accept this formula close ~ open + high + low + close. Because in this case I'd be telling R that I want it to incorperate the close value as well.

Comment: infact let me revise the question.

Comment: sure I understand this. I have revised the question to simplify this a little. :-)

Comment: Managed to revise the question again. If you could say what the formula would look like given my new description. Let me know.

Comment: Ok sure I will await your example. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Hi thanks for the very informative answer. I really do appreciate the time you have take to build out these answers with good well illustrated. Your example is very good.

Comment: Hey Bakkal , please see the new question I posted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38317260/r-neural-network-prediction-methods-compute-vs-prediction

Comment: hey, I noticed above you used "prediction(nn)", could you tell me if I should use prediction or the compute function? whats the difference? Both prediction and compute allow you to pass in values for which you want to predict the outcome for prediction uses a glm object where as compute uses a matrix of covariants.